# Trimming blocks using whitespace control from jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to print a single blank line surrounding the results of a jinja2 for loop, but I just can't get it to work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment

template = Template("""This is some text that should have a single blank line below it.

{% for i in range(10) -%}
line {{ i }}
{% endfor %}

This is some text that should have a single blank line above it.""")

template.environment = Environment(trim_blocks=True)

print(template.render())
```

This is the result I get:

```
This is some text that should have a single blank line below it.

line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9


This is some text that should have a single blank line above it.
```

However, I'm trying to configure it so that I don't get two blank lines above the final line, only one.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I worked it out. I was using the environment incorrectly. From the docs:

> Instances of this class [Environment] may be modified if they are not shared and if no
>   template was loaded so far. Modifications on environments after the
>   first template was loaded will lead to surprising effects and undefined behavior.

The correct code is below

```
from jinja2 import Environment

template_string = """This is some text that should have a single blank line below it.

{% for i in range(10) -%}
line {{ i }}
{% endfor %}

This is some text that should have a single blank line above it."""

env = Environment(trim_blocks=True)

template = env.from_string(template_string)

print(template.render())
```

and the result:

```
This is some text that should have a single blank line below it.

line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9

This is some text that should have a single blank line above it.
```

Answer (score 1):

`line {{ i }}` prints text followed by a newline, then you have an empty lines which makes it two. Simply remove an empty line:

```
template = Template("""This is some text that should have a single blank line below it.

{% for i in range(10) -%}
line {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
This is some text that should have a single blank line above it."""
```

Comment: sorry, this is not really what I was looking for, because I wanted to trim the blocks and that wasn't working. But thanks for your help anyway! :)